Handling Argument Counts in Custom Functions in Mathematica
I'm working on a custom function, and I'm encountering an issue with verifying the number of arguments passed to the function. I want to ensure that my function only works with a specific number of arguments (between 2 and 3).
Here's my current implementation:
myFunction[expr_, vars_?AtomQ | vars_?ListQ, attrs___] := 
  Module[{argList, argCount},
   argList = {expr, vars, attrs};
   argCount = Length[argList];
   If[argCount < 2 || argCount > 3,
    Message[myFunction::argcount, argCount],
    Print["Number of arguments is correct."]]
   ];

myFunction::argcount = 
  "myFunction was called with `1` argument(s); 
   between 2 and 3 arguments are expected.";

When I call myFunction with a single argument, say myFunction[1], the error message is not triggered as expected. How can I modify my function to ensure that it correctly handles and reports errors when the number of arguments is not within the expected range?
Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions!

Why not use CheckArguments?

You're right! I'll check out the documentation. Thanks for the help, @Domen!
